# Pulumi - EFS Id output to EC2 LaunchConfiguration UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs, pulumi

Using Pulumi, I created an EFS filesystem.
I want to add the mount to a launch configuration userdata by adding:
`mount -t efs -o tls fs-xxx:/ /mnt/efs`.
How can I add the efs.id to the launch configuration userdata?
(I can't convert an output to a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *convert* an Output to a string, but you can write a string once the output has resolved. You do this with an `apply`.

You can also use the `@pulumi/cloudinit` package to make this easier.

The following example is in typescript, but should apply to all Pulumi SDKs:

```js
import * as cloudinit from "@pulumi/cloudinit";

const efs_fs = new aws.efs.FileSystem("foo", {
});

const userData = efs_fs.id.apply(id => cloudinit.getConfig({
    gzip: false,
    base64Encode: false,
    parts: [{
        contentType: "text/cloud-config",
        content: JSON.stringify({
            packages: [
            ],
            mounts: [\"${id}\", '/mnt/efs'],
            bootcmd: [
            ],
            runcmd: [
            ]
        })
    },
```

You can then pass `userData.rendered` to any resource you're trying to create